# how to connect php variable to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php

hi i have a javascript variable and a php variable how can i connect them like following sample codes?

**index.php**

```
<div id="passh">mzage</div>

<script>
var passh = document.getElementById("passh").innerHTML;
</script>


<?php
$passh ="(javascript variable here)"; 

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','users');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '". $passh ."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo  $row['pass'] ;
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: jquery.ajax / html form post should solve this

Comment: how, please help its necessary

Comment: Save it to a file, and read / write to that file to get / set it as needed. The performance might not be very good, but it could be the easyest way.

Comment: @mzage: You need to understand how client-side and server-side code is separate.  PHP code can't access something that's in JavaScript.  If the data that you need exists server-side at any point, then your PHP code can access it.  But if it only exists client-side (something dynamically created with client-side code, for example) then JavaScript is going to need to make an AJAX request to a server-side resource (PHP page) to *send* that data.  It's not something that the PHP code which *already ran* for this page can access.

Comment: @JonasCz: And if the browser and web server are on different machines (which is pretty likely), how is the JavaScript and PHP code going to access the same file system?

Comment: @David, The original version of the question mentioned Java, not  JavaScript, so my comment relates to that. I was assuming he wanted to do some sort of communication between his Java and php code on the server. Deleting comment...

Comment: Post the data without loading page using ajax / Keep that value in session/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about JavaScript, not Java.

The Answer is, you can't. PHP works on the server and JavaScript on the client. PHP has already done it's job before JavaScript starts working.

You can use AJAX, asynchronous JavaScript, to send a http-request to a php-script which then returns a response to the client.
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

You could also use jQuery to send the Ajax-call ([the http-request via JavaScript),

[my opinion] it is a little easier to read and write than the original JavaScript.[my opinion] http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: how can i use ajax in same page

Comment: can i use xmlhttp.open("GET","**index.php**?q="+str,true); in **index.php**

Comment: I guess you could. But I would rather write a separate php-script which is meant to receive this request, so your code in the index.php doesn't get messy.